# Equality of continued fraction expansions

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, continued-fractions

Consider the two continued fraction expansions

$$
F(q,z) = \frac{1}{1- \frac{z}{1-qzF(q,qz)}}
$$

and

$$
G(q,z) = \frac{q^{-1}}{1 - \frac{qz}{1-qzG(q,qz)}}.
$$

Is it true that $F(q,z) = G(q,z)$?

Comment: Hint: $F(q,0)= 1, \quad G(q,0)= q^{-1}$

Comment: ah, of course. thanks!